# phpmyadmin show 404 not found in nginx

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I deploy my laravel application and it's working fine. My default file

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html/partex-star/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php  index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name 103.209.11.41;
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }


        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
         }
}
```

And then I add these codes to access my phpmyadmin by http:://ip_address/PhpMyAdmin. But now, It shows 404 not found.

```
       location /phpmyadmin {
                alias /usr/share/nginx/html/phpmyadmin;
                try_files $uri  @phpmyadmin;
                allow 103.209.11.41;
                deny  all;

                index index.php;
                location ~* \.php$ {
                        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                }
        }
```

I already create symlink.

Comment: How did you solve it ?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/index.php

```/index.php``` was solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this link it should be work http://103.209.11.41/phpmyadmin/index.php